# Using PayPal to pay end users

Tags: ios, paypal, payment-gateway

I am developing an iOS application that rewards users for specific activities with cash payments. Yes, I understand there are restrictions on this with the App Store and I've considered these. My questions is specifically about the PayPal SDK and whether it is suitable for allowing an iOS application to connect with a user's PayPal account, so the user can elect to receive payment for their rewards. Essentially, I need a "receive payment" button in lieu of a "Pay Now" button. My questions is about iOS specifically and whether or not the PayPal SDK is suitable for receiving payments as a user.

Comment: I don't see how that would work; a user can't just unilaterally transfer money from a PayPal account. They can send you a request for payment; this could just be an email sent via MailGun or an entry in a database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PayPal-iOS-SDK is for enabling a user/customer to authorize and pay for purchases, or pre-authorize future payments for purchases. Not what you seem to be looking for.

Instead, check out PayPal's [Payouts](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payouts/) API, which replaces the never-to-be-depreciated [MassPay](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mass-pay/gs_MassPay/) API (for the differences, see [this Stack Overflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31174340/4898050)). There's also a remote possibility that you're a candidate for the [AdaptivePay](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/) APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I checked out the SDK and it does indeed provide the services I need. Thanks AmitaiB.